# Shortest Path for n entities

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to solve a problem that is about minimizing the distance traveled by a group of n entities who have to go trough a group of x points in a given order.

The n entities all start in the same position (1,1) and then I'm given x points that are in a queue and have to be "answered" in the correct order. However, I want the distance to be minimal.

My approach to the algorithm so far was to order the entities in increasing order of their distance to the x that is next in line. Then, I'd check, from the ones that are closer to the ones that are the furthest away, if this distance to the next in line is bigger than the distance to the one that comes afterwards to minimize the distance. The closest one to not fulfill this condition went to answer. If all were closer to the x that came afterwards, I'd reorder them in increasing order of distance to the one that came afterwards and send the furthest away from this to answer the x. Since this is a test problem I'm doing as practice for a competition I know what the result should be for my test case and it seems I'm doing this wrong.

How should I implement such an algorithm that guarantees that the distance is minimal?

Comment: It's not clear from your wording: does every entity have to go through all points in the given order?

Comment: Isnt the "Traveling Salesman" problem? If so, its NP complete, meaning we dont know how to solve it in an efficient way

Comment: @TedHopp sorry about the wording. No, there is no requirement for every entity to go through every point, only that every point has to be answered in the specified order by one of the entities

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. @tomer.z - It's not exactly TSP, because there are several "travelers." Also, OP doesn't care about efficient; he just needs an algorithm that gives the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. Right now it's just not outputting a correct solution

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you've described sounds like a [greedy search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm). Greedy algorithms are not guaranteed to find optimal solutions except under specific conditions that don't seem to hold here.

This looks like a candidate for a [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) formulation. Alternatively, you can use heuristic search such as the [A* search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). I'd go with the latter if I was in the competition. See the link for a description of how the algorithm works, how to implement it, and how you might apply it to your problem.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for not having noticed your answer. The way I solved the problem was using a depth first search but it's not as efficient as it should. I looked into memoization but in this particular case I don't think it would actually improve the performance

Answer (score 0):

Although since the points need to be visited in order, there is a bound on the number of possible arrangements, I couldn't think of a more efficient way than the following formulation. Let `f(ns, i)` represent the optimal arrangement up to the `i`th point, where `ns` is the list of the last chosen point for each entity that has at least one point. Then we have at most two choices: either start a new entity if we haven't run out, or try the current point as the next visit for each entity.

Python recursion:

```py
import math

def d(p1, p2):
  return math.sqrt(math.pow(p1[0] - p2[0], 2) +  math.pow(p1[1] - p2[1], 2))

def f(ps, n):
  def g(ns, i):
    if i == len(ps):
      return 0

    # start a new entity if we haven't run out
    best = d((0,0), ps[i]) + g(ns[:] + [i], i + 1) if len(ns) < n else float('inf')

    # try the current point as the next visit for each entity
    for entity_idx, point_idx in enumerate(ns):
      _ns = ns[:]
      _ns[entity_idx] = i
      best = min(best, d(ps[point_idx], ps[i]) + g(_ns, i + 1))

    return best

  return d((0,0), ps[0]) + g([0], 1)
```

Output:

```py
"""
p5

p3

p1

(0,0)    p4  p6

p2
"""
points = [(0,1), (0,-1), (0,2), (2,0), (0,3), (3,0)]

print f(points, 3) # 7.0
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer! if i'm not mistaken that algorithm is a greedy search algorithm which does not suffice for this problem. since posting the question the only solution I could find for this problem was bruteforce-ish. I used a depth first search on a tree with all the possible paths and rejected whenever my distance was already exceeding my best distance so far. However this isn't a sufficiently efficient solution and I'm still unable to come up with one

Comment: @JoséPedro I think the example I posted is not greedy. It is also a search bound by the order of points. Is there some example data (and known solution) you could share that we could test?

Comment: for example, the following input, which reads: first line contains an integer n of the number of entities, the 2 line contains an integer p of the number of points, next p following lines are the points, then a line with an integer o for the order in which the points should be visited and the next o lines the points:
2 \n
3 \n
2 1 \n
3 2 \n
5 1 \n
5 \n
3 \n
2 \n
1 \n
2 \n
1 \n

The solution to this case is that the minimum movements required is 8

Comment: @JoséPedro I don't understand. In your example, `d((0,0), (5,1))` is 5.09, `d((0,0), (3,2))` is 3.6, and `d((5,1), (3,2))` is 2.23. If we only visited the third and then the second point (coming either from the third point or from (0,0)) we're almost at 8 total distance. You might need to clarify what you mean by `movements` or `distance` as you stated in the question.

Comment: ahhh, i forgot to mention... sorry about that. i'm not considering euclidean distance, it's manhattan distance. and it's that the minimum total distance is 8. you can visualize it by moving someone to the further away point, back to one of the closer ones, moving the other and now they dont have to move anymore

Comment: @JoséPedro ah, thanks for explaining. What you're describing sounds significantly different from how I interpreted your question. It would help greatly if you clarify *in the question*, exactly how `distance` is measured, as well as what you mean by "minimize the distance." Please also describe in detail how you arrived at the answer 8. I still don't understand it. It seems to me that a Manhattan visit from (0,0) to (5,1) is 6, and just one more visit from any point to any point would be at least 3 more.

Comment: the starting position is (1,1). again, sorry for the lack of clarification

Comment: @JoséPedro that still doesn't explain how "total distance" is calculated. I don't undrrstand how 8 is achieved. Could you please add a description *in the question* of one example including exact details of how the answer is measured? (Perhaps you can use the example we discussed in these comments.)